# it is possible to ignore the last element of the list?

Tags: python, list, loops, schedule, items

I have 2 lists that have work hours and work to do

```
hours = ["00:00","06:00","08:30","09:30","10:30","12:30","14:30","16:00","18:00",]
jobs  = [job1,job2,job3,job4,job5,job6,job7,job8,job9]
```

with a loop to use the schedule library to schedule the jobs.

```
for i,x in zip(hours,jobs):
    schedule.every().monday.at(i).do(x)
    schedule.every().tuesday.at(i).do(x)
    schedule.every().wednesday.at(i).do(x)
    schedule.every().thursday.at(i).do(x)
    schedule.every().friday.at(i).do(x)

while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

what I want to do is that on Fridays `schedule.every().friday.at(i).do(x)` I schedule all the jobs **except the last one**

`job9 at 18:00`

Is there any way to avoid the last item in the list in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Ismail's answer will avoid scheduling the last job on ALL days. If you want only Friday to be affected place the `if` statement before Friday:

```py
for i,x in zip(hours,jobs):
    schedule.every().monday.at(i).do(x)
    schedule.every().tuesday.at(i).do(x)
    schedule.every().wednesday.at(i).do(x)
    schedule.every().thursday.at(i).do(x)
    if i != hours[-1]:
        schedule.every().friday.at(i).do(x)
```

Comment: That was very easy haha. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add an `if` condition to check if its at the last element of a list:

```
for i,x in zip(hours,jobs):
    if i = hours[-1]:
        break
    schedule.every().monday.at(i).do(x)
    schedule.every().tuesday.at(i).do(x)
    schedule.every().wednesday.at(i).do(x)
    schedule.every().thursday.at(i).do(x)
    schedule.every().friday.at(i).do(x)
```

This keeps on looping until it reaches the last element (`hours[-1]`) where it breaks out of the loop.

Comment: this will avoid scheduling the last job every day. but thank you very much for helping. in the end it was the same but only in the fridays part